# Strange API activity

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

Was few days away from the computers and when back to work I found this very strange activity on my ape requests graph.

I have nothing running whole weekend.

Looks like some think monitoring each 3 seconds.
Do you know what it can be or what to check?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your [Admin console](http://console.developers.google.com) and from there check on the logs for your app

(under "Monitoring - > Logs").  This will tell you what was the request that caused a request to appear. Without access to your logs it's the best I can offer from here.

and 0.033 request a second is every 30 seconds, not every 3.

Comment: In my monitoring->log i have only: Nothing has been logged yet

Logs let you see events that happen when your app is running on Google App Engine   


Should i do the get started with App Engine ?

Comment: hmmm technically request logs should appear no matter whaton your admin console.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging pretty much explains that requests should always be available. You might need to filter differently.